# What does "abuse" and "gnashing teeth" mean in Charles Darwin's letter?

Tags: meaning, usage, politeness

In a letter by Charles Darwin to his friend, J.D. Hooker, he said the following at the end of the letter:

> In a year or two's time, when I shall be at my species book (if I do
>   not break down), I shall **gnash my teeth** and **abuse** you for having put
>   so many hostile facts so confoundedly well.

I wish to understand what Darwin meant by "gnashing his teeth" and
"abusing" his friend. I don't think that he meant illtrating or
scolding him, knowing that they were close friends, and due to the
fact that people were so polite in addressing each other back then.

Comment: Most people today would use ***curse*** rather than ***abuse*** in this kind of context. To ***gnash one's teeth*** is a "fixed expression" meaning [*to express strong emotion (usually rage / anger / frustration)*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gnash-one-s-teeth), but the verb ***to gnash*** is rarely used in any other contexts today. Darwin is being a bit jocular / facetious, but essentially he's telling Hooker that he (Darwin) expects to have to work very hard to come up with a theory that takes account of all the "awkward" facts Hooker has presented to him.

Comment: ...Darwin wouldn't have used ***curse*** because even if he weasn't fanatically religious himself, he wouldn't want to offend anyone (such as his wife) who *was* deeply religious, and might resent the "profanity". But essentially, he's ***teasing*** his friend, not really complaining.

Comment: @FumbleFingers why isn't this an answer?

Comment: @WendyG: Because I don't really understand what the OP here finds confusing. The phrase ***to gnash one's teeth*** can easily be looked up (I included a dictionary link in my first comment), and ***abuse*** is a straightforward literal usage (except for the fact that Darwin is lightheartedly ***joking / teasing***). So what exactly *is* the problem here?